# Need to make the window active

Tags: python, windows, winapi, autoit

I tried using two libraries:

1. win32
2. autoit

But none of them works correctly.

Сode example:

```
import autoit
import win32gui


hWnd = autoit.win_get_handle('[CLASS:Notepad]')

win32gui.SetActiveWindow(hWnd)
autoit.win_active_by_handle(hWnd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function to find window by class name:

```
import win32gui

def window_get(window=None, class_name:str=None)->int:
    ''' Returns hwnd. If window is not specified then
        finds foreground window.
    '''
    if isinstance(window, str):
        return win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window)
    elif isinstance(window, int):
        return window
    elif not window and class_name:
        return win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window)
    else:
        return win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
```

Usage:

```
import win32con

hwnd = window_get(class_name='Notepad')
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
```